# Refreshing data automatically in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am using the free version of Power BI Desktop (I am new, this is the first time I use it). I have a dashboard which has many tabs. I have configured SQL Server Database to be the source of the data displayed.

SQL Server Database tables are being updated every 15 minutes by a job in SQL, but in order to reflect these changes in my dashboard I manually need to click on "Update" button at the top bar in Power BI in order to display the new refreshed data into the dashboard. I have been trying to find an option in Power BI to configure the update process to be automatic but without success.

Is it possible to configure Power BI Desktop in order to update the data displayed in the dashboard automatically every x minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in Power BI Desktop. You need to publish your report to schedule refreshes.

Comment: Yep. Power BI Desktop is intended for building reports rather than consuming them.

Comment: ok, so If I want to schedule refreshes I will need to publish it. And if I want to publish it I will need to install Power BI report server which is not free, right? or is there a version of Power BI report server for free? I want to install for private use, not for comercial use.

Comment: Power BI Report Server is like SSRS (Sql Server Reporting Services), if you're familiar with that. So you'd use that, for example, to email reports. That is not free. To publish, you'd publish to the Power BI Service (by hitting the "Publish" button in Power BI Desktop). For this you need (at a minimum) a Power BI Pro license, as would anyone who consumes the reports you publish. That starts at USD $10 per month per user.

Comment: How-to  schedule refreshes in Power BI Pro  or  Power BI report server ?